# How to deploy a Rust web service on IIS?

Tags: iis, rust

I'm trying to deploy a web service written in Rust to the Mochahost Windows server. I found [Suave in IIS - Hello world](https://blog.vbfox.net/2016/03/31/Suave-in-IIS-hello-world.html) but `HttpPlatformHandler` is [replaced by ASP.NET Core Module](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164).

I tried to replace '..\MySite.exe' in the following line but that did not work:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="..\MySite.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout" />
```

Comment: “that did not work” isn't enough information for us to help you. How do you know it deosn't work? What kind of errors do you have? Do you have logs?

Comment: Non-ASP.NET Core projects should keep using HttpPlatformHandler.

Comment: Have you installed [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1)? and I suggest you add the full path for MySite.exe